# Shell script find occurrence of any character

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

How can I find if a pattern has occurred in a variable in if condition.

Eg:

```
var1="DEFABCTY"
var2="EFGH"
```

How can I use if in shell script to find which of the two variables has "ABC" using if statement.

Comment: This is quite simple and has been asked many times. What have you tried and what are you missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pattern matching and variable indirection:

```
for var in var1 var2 ; do
    if [[ ${!var} = *ABC* ]] ; then
        echo ABC occurs in $var
    fi
done
```